# ASP.NET Page does not refresh after running a DELETE SQL Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio

I am using VS2005. Currently I have a delete linkButton in my gridview, and if I presses on it to delete a row, the GridView goes empty, and I will have to click on the link again to access the page.

Below is my codefor .aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ondatabound="gv_DataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Columns>
                         <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>

                              <asp:CheckBox ID="UserSelection" OnCheckedChanged="UserSelector_CheckedChanged" runat="server" />
                                 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" onclick="lnkDelete_Click" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Employee") %>' ></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Below is my code for .cs

```
protected void lnkDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)sender;
        string stid = lnk.CommandArgument.ToString();
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "DELETE FROM [UserDB]where Employee like '%"+stid+"%'";
        SqlDataSource1.DataBind();

    }
```

I have tried assigning my delete query to SqlDataSource1 and select query to source2, but if that's the case, my delete query would not work.

I have also tried using IsPostBack on my PageLoad method, but the GridView goes empty as well after clicking on the delete button.

Currently both of my queries are assigned to SqlDataSource1, and once the query is deleted, the page just go blank, although the query is deleted.

May I know how can I refresh the page or reload the GridView table after the delete query is ran?

Thank you.

---

Thanks to the help from you guys, the problem is solved. Currently my working code is as follows:

```
LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)sender; 
    string stid = lnk.CommandArgument.ToString();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("DATA-SOURCE");
    string sql = string.Format("DELETE FROM [UserDB] where Employee like '%{0}%'",stid);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,conn);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [UserDB]";
    SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
    Response.Redirect("/Project/UserList.aspx");
```

I used a sql connection string for the delete query, and sqldatasource for the select query afterwards, finally refreshed the page by using response.redirect. Hope it helped newbies like me who met this error too.

Great thanks to all who provided help

Comment: Try putting autopostback=true in your delete button markup code.

Comment: I guess you can do a gridview.DataBind() instead of sqlDatasource.databind. The gridviews databind internally performs the sqldatasource databind and also refreshes the gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
protected void lnkDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{ 
        LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)sender; 
        string stid = lnk.CommandArgument.ToString(); 
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(<put your connectionstring here>);
        string sql = string.Format("DELETE FROM [UserDB] where Employee like '%{0}%'",stid);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,conn);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();   
        BindTheGridView();

            //or you can use SelectCommand of your SqlDataSource1 and can bind again simply.
}
```

EDIT:

```
public void BindTheGridView()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Connstring);
        string sql = "Select * from [UserDB]";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dtb = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dtb);
        conn.Close();
        SqlDataSource1.DataSource = dtb;
        SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
    }
```

And you can call this for any time to bind the values.

Comment: I did not downvote... but the code you posted has some quirks - for example it is vulnerable to SQL injection AND the `conn` variable is referenced out of thin air...

Comment: Hi skk. I understand what your code is doing. I do not undstd why my GridView does not refresh after deletion even though I see that SqlDataSource1.DataBind();  should refresh it after running the delete query.

Comment: @skk The GridView still does not refresh

Comment: You forgot to set up the DataSource, before DataBind.

Comment: @Ofer u mean i should insert SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [UserDB]"; before the databind?

Comment: Those downvoting people doesnt have minimum common sense to comment.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you assigning a `DELETE` command to the `SelectCommand` property ?

Just run the DELETE on a separate [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) instance with [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) and commit. Another option is to use [`DeleteCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.deletecommand.aspx) of the existing `SqlDataSource`.

Another point:

The way you build the `DELETE` SQL is vulnerable to a **serious security problem** called SQL injection - easiest and best way to avoid that is to use bind parameters!

Comment: on a seperate instance means?

Comment: @RUiHAO just create a SqlCommand, assign it the SQL and parameters etc. - don't use the SqlDataSource to try to execute your DELETE.

Comment: @RUiHAO another option is to use `DeleteCommand` of the existing `SqlDataSource`.

Answer (score 2):

First you should read up on what databinding in ASP.NET can do for you. (Then you won't have to write any codebehind for this scenario.)

**Example:** (Not tested in VS)

You should use the SqlDataSource's DeleteCommand to set the delete command and its parameters like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="..."
        SelectCommand="..."
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [UserDB] WHERE Employee=@Employee">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Employee" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And the on the GridView, you should set the DataKeyNames property, and inside the ItemTemplate's Linkbutton you should set the CommandName property to "Delete" as shown below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
        ondatabound="gv_DataBound" DataKeyNames="Employee"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="UserSelection" runat="server"
                        OnCheckedChanged="UserSelector_CheckedChanged" />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server"
                        onclick="lnkDelete_Click" Text="Delete"
                        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Employee") %>'
                        CommandName="Delete" ></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong to run change operation (`DELETE` in your example) as a `SelectCommand`. `SelectCommand` must be used as it called - only to `SELECT`s.

Run the `DELETE` query separately, then run a `SELECT` command to show the relevant records for the grid.

Answer (score 0):

**SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "DELETE FROM [UserDB]where Employee like '%"+stid+"%'";
SqlDataSource1.DataBind();**

Why are you using Delete query in SelectCommand. The query is open to SqlInjection attack. I would have used a stored procedure and verify the parameter before passing it to the procedure.

Moreover the Grid won't show/bind any data as your code is not return any data back. It is just deleting the data.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do a gridview.DataBind() instead of sqlDatasource.databind. The gridviews databind internally performs the sqldatasource databind and also refreshes the gridview.